# SpringApplication is not closing after unit test in a Netty based application

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-boot-test

I have a Netty service that is "springified". The service runs fine and handles requests/responses.

I am not adding unit-tests/integration tests. I am seeing that the springcontext is not shutting down after the tests. I.e the netty server is running after the test is complete. I can telnet to the port and see it is still connected to it

Here is my SpringBootApp file

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NettyService {

    //Autowired all the required fields

    //I made this static so I can access from integration tests to shut it down. I shouldn't need
    //this since after each test jvm should be shut-down.
    static ChannelFuture serverChannelFuture;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(NettyService.class, args);

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() throws InterruptedException {
        serverChannelFuture = bootstrap.bind(tcpSocketAddress).sync();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
        serverChannelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }

}
```

**Test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=NettyService.class)
public class AppTest
{

    @After
    public void cleanUp() throws Exception {
        //NettyService.serverChannelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }


    @Test
    public void contextLoad1() throws Exception
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoad2() throws Exception
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
```

When the first test, it passes fine. but second test fails with "Address in use" error.
Netty is not tearing down after the first test is finished. I expect the spring context to close at end of test or atleast jvm exits.

Note, I have commented out the line in cleanUp() method. If I uncomment, even the first test is not run. It is just hanging forever.

Comment: It won't restart between tests unless you use an `@DirtiesContext` but else it will start once and be reused.

Comment: shouldn't the application shutdown at the end of tests? I run one test and after the test passes, it is still hanging there forever and I can ping the server on the port

Comment: If you run multiple test classes (an `@Test` method is the test not the class it id defined in my definition of a test) it will remain started until the very last test method of the last class has run. If you run only the class here there are 2 tests and it should shutdown after both methods have executed. If that doesn't happen, it has to do with your setup, which probably is due to the fact you are managing your own Netty instead of letting Spring Boot control the lifecycle.

Comment: I am letting Spring boot manage Netty. since it is not shutting down, I tried the hack to forcefully shutdown in cleanUp() which doesnt help either.

Comment: You aren't letting Spring Boot manage Netty as you have the `@PreDestroy` and `@PostConstruct` in your Spring Boot application. Which means you are actually controlling the Netty instance and not Spring Boot.

Comment: I see. what is an alternative/suggestion that you have

Comment: Without seeing your bootstrap code there isn't much advice. In first instance I would say use the Spring Boot default Netty instance (assuming you are on a version that supports Netty) instead of starting it yourself.

Comment: Bro, why is your embedded server running during unit tests? It is not like you are service http requests. And Unit tests aresupposed to be running offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shutting down Netty incorrectly.

> ```
> @PreDestroy
> public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
>     serverChannelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
> }
> ```

This is only waiting for the for the server channel to close, but it is never requesting it to actually close, this is going to block forever.

Instead of calling `.closeFuture()`(an event in the future), call `.close()`(Close it now).

```
@PreDestroy
public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
    serverChannelFuture.channel().close().sync();
}
```

If you also make a threadpool using a new instance of `NioEventLoopGoup`, make sure to also terminate that by calling its shutdown function after closing the channel.